# Laravel Cartalyst Cart error while installing via composer

Tags: git, laravel, composer-php

There are my composer requires

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "cartalyst/sentinel": "2.*",
    "illuminate/html": "5.*",
    "cartalyst/cart": "^2.0"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.cartalyst.com"
    }
],
```

git gives error saying "failed to execute git-clone --no-checkout".
Is there any problem with the cartalyst repo or is there error on my end?

Comment: Could you please amend your original post and include the complete error output while running the command in very verbose mode (`-vvv`)?

Comment: Here is the log from -vvv mode http://pasted.co/b166339b

Comment: Ok, it seems to be trying to use your github token to access the `cartalyst/conditions` repository @ github.com -- however this repository does not exist. So either it is private and you do not have access, or this is a misconfiguration somewhere (e.g. this dependency should not be there).

Comment: Have you used cartalyst cart package in laravel. If so How shall i install it?

Answer (score 0):

So, according to https://packages.cartalyst.com/#!/conditions, the package should be available on Github. But it's not. Either it is private, it was removed, or it was renamed and someone forgot to update it.

I recommend you reach out to the maintainers of the project to figure out what happened. This is not a Composer issue per se.

In the case that this is a private repository, and you should have access, make sure that you are using a Github token that specifically grants access to their repositories.

Comment: It is a premium package. So i needed to subscribe in order to get the repository.

Answer (score 0):

As noted on the [documentation](https://cartalyst.com/manual/cart/3.0) **cartalyst/cart** requires a valid [subscription](https://cartalyst.com/pricing).